# C# for loop in visual studio

Tags: c#, for-loop

```
    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Multiplication = Convert.ToInt32(txtMultiplication.Text);
        int Fnum = Convert.ToInt32(txtFnum.Text);
        int Tnum = Convert.ToInt32(txtTnum.Text);

        txtOutput.Text = "";
        for (Multiplication = 0; Fnum <= Tnum; Fnum++)
        {
            output = output + Multiplication;
            res = Multiplication * Fnum;
            if (Fnum <= Tnum)
                continue;
        } // while Fnum <= Tnum

        txtOutput.Text = output;
    } // end method
```

I have 3 textboxes in layout.
First, I change textbox string to interger.
Second, I need to make loop(Fnum to Tnum).
The question is I do not know how to make loop in this question.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're trying to achieve. Why are you reading an integer from the textfield (Multiplication) and then assigning 0 to it afterwards? if you want to loop from FNum to TNum it could look something like this:

```for (int i = FNum; i <= TNum; i++)
{
    //loop body
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, you just need to declare local variable initialized with `Fnum`

```
for (var i = Fnum; i <= Tnum; i++)
{
    // do something with i
}
```